# Jquery addClass if image height greater than the width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have one question about jquery addClass image.

I am trying this think in this **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/VLyPOK)** from codepen.io

So the problem is the javascript is not adding class from the image if image height greater than the width. Anyone can help me in this regard ?

This is my test jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var img = document.getElementById('.user_posted_image');
  //or however you get a handle to the IMG
  var width = img.clientWidth;
  var height = img.clientHeight;

  if(width < height){
     $('img').addClass('portrait');
  }
});
```

Comment: Why are you passing a class selector to `getElementById`?

Comment: images are not loaded fully when document ready is fired. You can not use a class name with getElementById

Comment: Also `$('img').addClass('portrait')` will add the class to ALL images on that page. If you want to make your `img` var into a jquery object, it's `$(img)` (without quotes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `$(".user_posted_image")` instead of `document.getElementById('.user_posted_image')`. You are trying to get an item by [.classSelector](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/).

`document.getElementById` it is just for identifiers, But if you have the jQuery library, you can use [#idSelector](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) instead. Also, you can take advantage of  [jQuery.width()](http://api.jquery.com/width/) and [jQuery.height()](http://api.jquery.com/height/) methods.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var img = $('#user_posted_image');//jQuery id selector

  var width = img.width(); //jQuery width method
  var height = img.height(); //jQuery height method

  if(width < height){
     img.addClass('portrait');
  }
});
```

```
<img id="user_posted_image" src="image.png" width="100" height="150" />
```

**Edit (Demo CodePen)**: You are using multiple images, you should use the [.each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) method to refer to all elements, in the first code only works in one element.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var imgs = $('.imgpreview');//jQuery class selector
  imgs.each(function(){
    var img = $(this);
    var width = img.width(); //jQuery width method
    var height = img.height(); //jQuery height method
    if(width < height){
       img.addClass('portrait');
    }else{
       img.addClass('landscape');
    }
  })
});
```

Comment: `$('img')`in your example should just be `img`

Comment: @wzvang thanks for your answer but it is not added a class from the image.

Comment: @innovation Updated `img.addClass('portrait')`, try the new code. PS: `user_posted_image` is a class or id ?

Comment: I still try this please check the same demo. everything is same. The image not have portrait class

Comment: Your are using `class="user_posted_image"` or `id="user_posted_image"`? , for class selectors use **[.user_posted_image](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/)**, for id use: **[#user_posted_image](https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/)**

Comment: I understood now what you mean. Thanks your answer. I am waiting to give you a point. ;)

Comment: @wZVanG Dear sir the code is added class all the image not `width < height`  please help me. [DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/VLyPOK)

Comment: @wZVanG just one more question how can i call this function with ajax click ?

Comment: in that case, you call the function after the Ajax load, but if is another problem you can create a new question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81730/discussion-between-innovation-and-wzvang).

Answer (score 2):

Guessing you want something like this: http://codepen.io/BramVanroy/pen/MwrJMx

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var img = $('.user_posted_image');
  img.each(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        width = $this.children("img").width(),
        height = $this.children("img").height();
    if (width < height) {
      $this.addClass('portrait');
    } else {
      $this.addClass('landscape');
    }
  });
});
```

Iterate over all the divs with the designated class. If the image that's inside has a width that's smaller than its height: add class portrait. Else: add class landscape.

**NOTE**: as has been pointed out in the comments, you'll need to wait for the images to load to succesfully run this script. I have succesfully used the [imagesLoaded plugin](https://github.com/desandro/imagesloaded) in the past.

---

Including the imagesLoaded plugin, it will look like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".chated-poeople").imagesLoaded(function() {
    var img = $('.user_posted_image');
    img.each(function() {
      var $this = $(this),
        width = $this.children("img").width(),
        height = $this.children("img").height();
      if (width < height) {
        $this.addClass('portrait');
      } else {
        $this.addClass('landscape');
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Don't forget to add the plugin in your HTML:

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.imagesloaded/3.1.8/imagesloaded.pkgd.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. But @wZVanG answer is a little good for me. But there is one problem if you can check my demo again then you can see the portrait is added all the image class. The javascript function should added `if(width<height) {}` can you help me in this regard ?

Comment: You keep asking extra questions. This is not how you are ought to ask questions on SO. Be as specific as possible. You should have asked your Ajax requirement beforehand. Portrait is added to all elements because @wZVanG doesn't check the width of the *images* but of their containers.