# How HTML can show Horizontal image vertically?

Tags: html, css

HTML Horizontal image showing vertically. If you open image link in the browser you can see it in horizontal mode originally it is a horizontal. How can I display this image in horizontal format?

```html
<img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/794489/20180630_194239.jpg">
```

Comment: if you cannot use transform can you be more precise?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: People have answered your question with a solution that works.  If it does not work for you, you need to provide more details in your question as to why it doesn't work and exactly how your image is rendered - you cannot just ask a question about how to rotate an image and shoot everyone down when they provide answers that don't fit with your hidden requirements

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
img {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/794489/20180630_194239.jpg">
```

Comment: I can't use the transform method image is dynamic. Please give me another option to handle this.

Comment: @ShahRushabh I did not get you properly. What do you mean by dynamic here. Explain properly.

Comment: Dynamic means loading from PHP. some have big width small height some have small width big height.

Answer (score 0):

Use transform BUT you need to adjust the origin and add some translation:

```css
img {
  transform:rotate(90deg) translateY(-100%);
  transform-origin:top left;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/794489/20180630_194239.jpg">
```

Or:

```css
img {
  transform:rotate(-90deg) translateX(-100%);
  transform-origin:top left;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/794489/20180630_194239.jpg">
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `transform` to rotate the image by `90 degree`

```css
.img {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  margin-left: 10%;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/794489/20180630_194239.jpg">
<hr>
<img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/794489/20180630_194239.jpg" class="img">
```

Comment: I can't use the transform method image is dynamic. Please give me another option to handle this.

Comment: that is why you should use the class to the image you need to display horizontally.

Answer (score -2):

Use this:

```css
img {
transform: rotate(90deg);
margin-left: 20%;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/794489/20180630_194239.jpg">
```

Comment: I can't use the transform method image is dynamic. Please give me another option to handle this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31090542/jquery-addclass-if-image-height-greater-than-the-width - take a look at this one! It will solve your problem hopefully.